# Brownian motion, compact interval

Tags: limits, derivatives, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)_{t\geq0}$ denote a standard Brownian motion and $I=\left[a,b\right]$ a compact interval. Show that
$P\left[\frac {W_{t+h}-W_t} {h} \in I\right] \rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$. What does this precisely mean for the differentiability of the Brownian paths?

My idea of proof is rather intuitive. The expression $P\left[\frac {W_{t+h}-W_t} {h} \in I\right] \rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$ reminds me of differentiability od real function of one variable.
I see that for $h=0$ the fraction is $\frac {0} {0}$, which means the limit is undefined and therefore cannot belong to $I$, as it is compact. However I think it is not sufficient. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fraction is distributed like $\mathcal{N}(0,1/h)$, after invoking the definition of Brownian motion. As $h$ gets small, this distribution gets wider-and-wider. Meaning that any finite interval will have less-and-less probability (formally justify this by writing down the normal density and showing it goes to zero everywhere).

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you how you got $1/h$? I know that $W_{t+h}-W_t \sim N(0,h)$ from the definition..

Comment: It's $(1/h) \times N(0,h)$, since you're also dividing by $h$, which you can work out is distributed like $N(0,1/h)$. A nice way of remembering this is that $\mbox{Var}(aX) = a^2\mbox{Var}(X)$ which in this case gives $(1/h^2)\cdot h = 1/h$

Comment: And how about the second part of the question?What does this precisely mean for the differentiability of the Brownian paths? I know BM is not differentiable in general, so is this a special case?

Comment: If you take the limit inside the probability, this implies Brownian motion is almost surely nondifferentiable, as the limiting distribution is 0 everywhere and hence not a probability distribution.